# MySQL auto sync master slave replication

Tags: mysql, linux, replication

I have set up a master slave replication with MySQL. Now I am facing an issue. If master instance goes down or unreachable and when its come up or reachable replication stops. I want that when the master comes up or reachable slave can sync changes automatically.

**mysql master status**

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 192.168.1.33
                  Master_User: replica
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000020
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 433
               Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000002
                Relay_Log_Pos: 266
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000020
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 433
              Relay_Log_Space: 423
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Everything looks good but replication stopped.
I need someone's experts help....

Comment: Did you try running on the server instance the `SHOW MASTER STATUS\G` command?

Comment: @Gooseman i am trying to do this in my local network . master with windows pc and slave is linux machine.